# How to update SQL Server Metadata using SharePoint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, metadata

Is it possible to view and update metadata from SQL Server in SharePoint?

I’m asking because I would like to create a SharePoint site where I have a “library” that can search for all sorts of databases based on keywords, etc… and I would like the metadata of a desired search result (.dbo metadata) to appear and allow it to be editable IN SharePoint (without having to go to SQL Server and do it there- AND at the same time, the changes would automatically register in SQL server as well).

Is this possible?

Comment: What metadata exactly do you want to edit?  This sounds like a pretty bad idea to be honest.

Comment: Metadata from tables in SQL. I dont think it's a bad idea b/c I eventually want to create a "library" on the SharePoint site where I can type in a keyword/tag and get a list of all the tables that have the keyword as part of its metadata. Then I can select the desired result I'm looking for in the SharePoint site and make changes to the metadata if I wanted to (and have those changes automatically logged in the SQL database as well).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing your metadata 'tags' in a sharepoint list (or maybe differet categories of metadata in several sharepoint lists) and then using a lookup field (linked to your sharepoint 'tags' lists) which allows multiple items to be selected as a metadata in a field (or several fields) against the documents in the document library? That way you keep your metadata managed nice and easily in sharepoint and can filter the documents author any custom development?

Hope this helps or at least gives you another option for the way you look at solving your problem...

Comment: Thanks Luke but I don't think this type of approach applies because I will be searching External Data using BCS. It's not a document, it's a SQL database. As for tagging and all that good stuff, that' is a great way to do that but I'm not creating a list. I'm just connecting to an external source to get the data displayed in a web part and making it editable.